# ZXing scanning intent

Tags: android, zxing, onactivityresult

i added Zxing library to my project .It works well but i didnt receive result of scanning on my **MainActivity**(when scan successfull,it didnt return me to **MainActivity**,just show a result on **capture.xml**), what i do wrong?

**MainActivity :**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
    onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, i);
    String contents = null;

    if (requestCode == 1) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            contents = i.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = i.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText(contents);
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}

public void onCapture(View view) {
    Intent i=new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("SCAN_MODE","QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(i,1);


}
```

}

Comment: `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
    onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, i);` = endless recursion?!

Comment: @HannoBinder  so i must delete onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, i) ?

Comment: Yes. - Or rather, call `super.onActivityResult` *only* if the `requestCode` is not one you're handling.

Comment: @HannoBinder i call 'super.onActivityResult'  and still nothing, i dont understand where i make mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE");
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Comment: thanks, now it return to **MainActivity**, but didnt tranfer data to **textView**, where is now my mistake?

Comment: if you debug that: contents = i.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"); did you see any value on contents?

Comment: Oh, thanks u a lot, i found my mistake, i have **if (requestCode == 0)** , when i changed it to **if (requestCode == 1)** program start to work correctly